# Best practices: Global objects vs modules

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm currently working on a project and have seen the below code used to store each "Module" (as such) in the window object. I've done a fair amount of Javascript over the years and from my understanding of best practices is that you want to avoid polluting the global namespace. Would this be considered polluting the global namespace?

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    // Public methods.
    var exports = {};

    /*
    * Some other configuration / members
    *
    */

    global.Helper = exports.members;
    return exports;

}(window));
```

I'm accustom to using module pattern to structure my Javascript.

Example below.

```
var module = (function () {

    var defaultOptions = {
        //some options
    };

    var init = function (options) {
        defaultOptions = $.extend(defaultOptions, options, false);

    };

    /*
    * More code
    *
    */

    //public functions
    return {
        init: init
    }


})();
```

From a best practice stand point am I right in my understanding or have I completely missed the boat?

Is it acceptable practice to store each module in the window object?

Comment: "thus avoiding storing anything in a global namespace" --- but `var module` is defined in a global space.

Comment: Fair comment, reworded the post

Comment: You have to put **something** in the global namespace, or applications won't be able to use it. But you can minimize the pollution, by using just a single name for your entire namespace, and use properties within that for each module. Like the way all jQuery plugins are `$.something`.

Comment: I think the point that zerkms is making is that after you have run your second code snippet, you have `window.module === {init:function{...}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to put module in global space, because everyone who will use your module would be forced to use it only with a window variable.

Another reason - do window object will always be defined?

All of the famous JavaScript modules are defined in global scope: jquery, prototype, yii etc.